# OpenMP - Running parallel code inside parallel code

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a function `compute()` that has parallelized matrix multiplication inside of it using OpenMP

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

This function is called many times in a loop - which I would like to run in parallel.
Will there be any issues in running parallel code inside other parallel code?

This is c++ compiled on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will work fine, but you'll need to enable OpenMP nesting for it to work.

Call

```
omp_set_nested(1);
```

at the start of the program and it will allow you to have nested parallel regions.

However: Be aware, that you could end up running many more threads than what you want. So you will want to limit the # of threads of both the top and inner parallel regions.

Comment: This is excellent. I forgot the word nested, and couldn't find anything useful.